# What is the number that comes after the interface name in “ifconfig -a” output?

Tags: networking, unix, ifconfig

What are these numbers 2043, 2091, 2276, 2324 that comes after the interface name—such as `eth4` in this example—when I use `ifconfig -a`?

```
eth4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:53:27:81:00  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:53ff:fe27:8100/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:57475580 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19428989 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8432560535 (7.8 GiB)  TX bytes:3992007736 (3.7 GiB)
          Interrupt:32 

eth4.2043 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:53:27:81:00  
          inet addr:10.253.33.167  Bcast:10.253.33.175  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:53ff:fe27:8100/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:33 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:137550 (134.3 KiB)  TX bytes:1698 (1.6 KiB)

eth4.2091 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:53:27:81:00  
          inet addr:208.92.146.44  Bcast:208.92.146.47  Mask:255.255.255.248
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:53ff:fe27:8100/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:347 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:14634 (14.2 KiB)  TX bytes:16222 (15.8 KiB)

eth4.2276 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:53:27:81:00  
          inet addr:10.55.37.64  Bcast:10.55.37.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:53ff:fe27:8100/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6033 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:632 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:367624 (359.0 KiB)  TX bytes:30792 (30.0 KiB)

eth4.2324 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:53:27:81:00  
          inet addr:10.253.64.70  Bcast:10.253.64.79  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:53ff:fe27:8100/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3312 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:76 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:139104 (135.8 KiB)  TX bytes:3816 (3.7 KiB)
```

Thanks in advance, I couldn't find this information in any place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are sub-interfaces. These are "logical" interfaces, so interfaces over a physical interface. As you can see, at the left side of the dot there is `eth4`, and at the right side the sub-interface ID. There might be many sub-interfaces over a single physical network card.

Each of these sub-interfaces may have its own IP address, netmask, gateway and other parameters.

Usually, the sub-interface ID matches the tagged VLAN that sends packet to that sub-interface, but it's not mandatory, just a convention.